# Return after clearInterval

Tags: javascript, function, return, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a code that runs setInterval in a function. What I try to achive is to exit from that function after clearInterval occured. I set up a condition to check wheter the interval is cleared. I'm struggling to find a method to return from the main Start() function based on the current state of the code.

Code:

```
function Start() {

    var elementX = document.getElementById('moveMeX')
    var elementY = document.getElementById('moveMeY')
    elementY.style.top = "0px"

    var posX = 0
    startPosX = 0
    var posY = 0
    startPosY = 0
    var speed = 1
    var xIsMoving = true
    var yIsMoving = true

    var myIntervalX = setInterval(function() {
        if(startPosX == 0) {
            posX+=speed
            elementX.style.left = posX + 'px'
            if(posX==100) {
                startPosX = 100
            }
        }
        else if (startPosX==100) {
            posX-=speed
            elementX.style.left = posX + 'px'
            if(posX==0) {
                startPosX = 0
            }
        }
    }, 10);
    
    function stopX() {
        clearInterval(myIntervalX);
        xIsMoving = false
    }
    
    elementX.addEventListener("mousedown", stopX);
    elementX.addEventListener("mousedown", startY);
    
    function startY() {
        var myIntervalY = setInterval(function() {
            if(startPosY == 0) {
                posY+=speed 
                elementY.style.top = posY + 'px'
                if(posY==100) {
                    startPosY = 100
                }
            }
            else if (startPosY==100) {
                posY-=speed
                elementY.style.top = posY + 'px'
                if(posY==0) {
                    startPosY = 0
                }
            }
        }, 10);
    
        function stopY() {
            elementY.style.zIndex = "-1";
            clearInterval(myIntervalY);
            yIsMoving = false
        }
        
        elementY.addEventListener("mousedown", stopY);
    }

    if (xIsMoving === false && yIsMoving === false) {
        console.log('stopped')
        stopped = true
    }
}

Start()
```

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/silentstorm902/pen/podNxVy

Comment: you dont need recursion, just a for loop calling Start

Comment: OK, but how do I return from the start function?

Comment: My answer below does not address your issue of recursion, but hopefully it helps with how you know when one "run" is complete.  If you need help with the recursion in addition (it doesn't look to me like your present recursion code will work), let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The part you state you have a problem with,

```
if (xIsMoving === false && yIsMoving === false) {
    console.log('stopped')
    stopped = true
}
```

currently only runs once: when Start() is first called.  At that time, both conditions are false because the variables have their initial declared values of *true*.

You *could* create a new `setInterval` to run this `if` statement every so often, but it seems unnecessary because your current stopY function is *really* the place where you know that both xIsMoving and yIsMoving are both false -- because stopY only runs after stopX has run. So just move your statement of `stopped=true` at the end of the stopY function:

```
function stopY() {
    elementY.style.zIndex = "-1";
    clearInterval(myIntervalY);
    yIsMoving = false;
    console.log("stopped");
    stopped = true;
}
```

Comment: But how can I use that information to return from the function?